# Socket.io - Implementing a user-socket association map for private messaging

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to create a private messaging system using socket.io

In order to associate the users with their sockets, most sites are suggesting something like this:

```
var people = {};

client.on('connection', function(socket) {

    //join the server
    socket.on('add user', function(user_id) {
        //create user-socket map
        people[user_id] = socket.id;
    });

});
```

In my opinion, the problem with the above code is that the `user_id` is sent from the client side, so if the user somehow modify it and send another `user_id` an impersonation will take place.

Also, I can't access `req.user._id` under `client.on('connection'...` so how am I supposed to get the `user_id` from the server's side? I'm using node.js, passport and express.

Comment: A module like [`socket.io-express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-express-session) allows you to share sessions between Express and socket.io, which seems to me what you want (alternative: [`express-socket.io-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `jsonwebtoken` and `socketio-jwt` modules for solving this security issue.

Server:

```
var secret = 'shhhhhh';
app.get('/getJWT', function(req, res) {
    /* Do your authentication here using header and get the userId */
    var userId = 'someId';
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    var token = jwt.sign({ 'userId': userId }, secret);
    res.json({
        token: token
    });
});

var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: secret,
    handshake: true
}));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var userId = socket.decoded_token.userId;
    /* your logic */
```

Client:

```
var token = "token you got from the /getJWT"
var c = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/', { query: "token=" + token });
```

As the token is encoded with a secret, client cannot change and send it.

Refer [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/) article to know why this is better.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the most important part... Your code has to verify the usr is who he says he is. Plain and simple. I've done this multiple ways:

If users are logging in via PHP code, I move the session data to a mysql database. I then use a string on the PHP side to generate a response for a challenge to the client, who sends it to my web socket server. The WS server will challenge the client and look up the session information in the mysqldb. Done.

In my more recent developments, the actual login process is done via the web socket server. I verify the user credentials via whatever DB (in my instance, MySQL) and tie the username to the socket. Finished...

Do not purely rely on the javascript-based site to say "My name is." Otherwise, as you said, user impersonation becomes a walk in the park. You *MUST* validate that the user is who he says he is IF you're implementing a system where that matters. "Web sockets" themselves are not magical components that do this for you.

Comment: Exactly! That's my problem, I can't access the session of the user under the ```client.on('connection'...``` to see who he really is

Comment: When/where is he logging in? You're going to have to come up with some form of logic to tie a variable to the connection upon login if authenticated successfully.

Comment: I have something like that it's the ```req.user._id``` but I can't access it and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

`var people` will be accessible on the same process.

When you want to scale with multiple socket server and balancing between them, then this idea for keeping people object locally will be not helpful.

Create `authenticate` event for authentication and set `socket.userId`  and `socket.isAuthenticate = true` flag. In other events if socket.isAuthenticate is false, kick them out.

Make use of 'socket.io-redis' adpater for communication among many socket.io server. ( So when user1 from server1 send message to user2 which is in server2, will work ).

For socket - user association with multiple process, you can join Room with their userId, on authentication, join room like `socket.join('myuserId');`

and when to send message to that user, you can use `io.to('myuserId').emit('message', "Hi How are you?"):`

Comment: Hm, yeah you are right about the people object, it shouldn't be kept locally. But regarding the socket - user association, you said to join room like ```socket.join('myuserId');``` how am I going to get the ```myuserId```, from the client?

Comment: Check "Create Authenicate event" part from my answer. From client emit authenticate with username and pwd /token to authenticate basend on that get userId

Comment: How do I check if the token is valid or not? May I see the code?

Comment: who are the users ? Do u have users database ?

Comment: Yeah, I have a users database, I'm using mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

you can Send additional data on socket connection like this:

```
 client side :

     var c = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/', { query: "userId=value01" });



server side :
 // extract userId param from connected url
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      var socket_param_userId = socket.handshake['query']['userId'];
      console.log(socket_param_userId);  //show value01
});
```

Comment: what if the client change the query to: ```{ query: "userId=another_user_id" }```??

Comment: You should send your data either in connect or on create of the socket connection and note that you can send multiple param

Comment: Yeah but my problem here is that the client has absolute control of what he can send. For example, he can say that he is someone else.

Comment: Can you tell me the context in which you want to implement this approach