# Getting the socket id,user id pair of a logged in user(s)

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I have a web application done using node js and in it,i have an authentication system that requires users to log in before they can access pages. I have only two pages,the homepage and the updates page.

From what i read from the docs,a new socket id is issued when a user opens a tab in the browser. Me being the admin,i would like to know the socket id of a logged in user and even more so,the socket id,logged in user id pair for all logged in users.

What method can i use to get the socket id,logged in user id pair to make sure i broadcast the realtime info to only users who are online?.

Comment: May be this answer will help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33974572/3492210

Comment: var userid = socket.id

Comment: Thanks Gary and Anand.